# With a complicated date column, I need to select maximum day in column + 4 hours from the previous one

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, filter

I would like to understand how to filter by specific date in my dataframe column.

I have one column - final_report['TemporaryDateFilter'], with all dates in this format:

2023-01-23 11:40:12

2023-01-25 01:30:42

2023-01-25 21:21:32

2023-01-24 05:36:07

...

(The report is updated every day with new data)

I would like to - Filter this column by date + hour + minutes - ranging from 20:01 from the day before the maximum day in the column to whatever is the maximum day in the column and with time being no later than 5:59 in that day.

So in this case it would select every record from 2023-01-24 20:01:00 to 2023-01-25 05:59:00

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` the input DataFrame with `date` the column:

```
# ensure datetime
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# get max day, rounded on midnight
max_day = s.max().normalize()

# remove 1 day, set the time to 20:01
start = max_day + pd.DateOffset(days=-1, hour=20, minutes=1)
# set the time to 05:59
end = max_day + pd.DateOffset(hour=5, minutes=59)

# filter
out = df[s.between(start, end)]
```

Output:

```
                  date
1  2023-01-25 01:30:42
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. It doesn't write any error when I run it, but It returns an empty dataframe.